# multi select to mysql where

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I have a multi-select box going to a PHP page which I am trying to take the selected values and place in a where statement. I can get the values back as 1 2 3 4 without the comma in-between. I have tried the implode and explode function with no luck.

```
foreach ($_POST['station'] as $stations)
echo  $station =  $stations."\n";
```

Comment: Can you add an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$stations_string = implode(" OR ", $_POST['station']);
```